# Работа telegram-бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Создаю telegram-бота, но хотел бы узнать, как можно улучшить его работу. Использую `polling` и вот такой вот обработчик

```
while True:
try:

    pool=threading.Thread(target=bot.polling(none_stop=True,  timeout=50))
    pool=threading.Thread(target=bot.infinity_polling(True))
    pool.start()

    bot.set_update_listener(listening)





except Exception:
    pass

except AttributeError:
    pass

except ReferenceError:
    pass

except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    pass

except ConnectionAbortedError:
    pass

except ConnectionRefusedError:
    pass

except ConnectionResetError:
    pass

except RuntimeError:
    pass

except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
    pass

except IndexError:
    pass

except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
    pass

except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.RetryError:
    pass

except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    pass

except telebot.apihelper.requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
    pass

except RecursionError:
    pass



finally:

    pass
```

Суть вопроса:

1. Как можно улучшить работу бота, чтобы он держался и не падал так часто, не переставал работать после длительного отсутствия обращений к нему.
2. Как лучше сделать, чтобы он работал: через Windows service или сделать его задачей через Диспетчер задач?
3. Почему бот может перестать работать если кинуть компьютер в сон на 30 минут?
4. ЧТо означает здесь `threated=False` `bot = telebot.TeleBot(self.token, threaded=False)`

Comment: Насчёт улучшить работу надо подумать, а вот чтобы улучшить код, уберите все `except`, кроме первого, и `finally` тоже. Все Ваши исключения попадут в первый обработчик, если класс исключений в `telebot` реализован правильно.

Comment: @V-Mor я роботал не через класс, а через функций

Comment: Даже если вы работали "через функций", исключения всё равно реализованы классом. И всё, что у Вас стоит после первого `except` – недостижимый код. А `finally: pass`, на мой взгляд, вообще бессмыслица.

Comment: @V-Mor хорошо, сейчас уберу, спасибо что подсказала. Но вопрос все равно остаеться тем же, как вообще можно улучшить. И два остольных вопроса

Comment: Насколько давно Вы программируете на Python?

Comment: @V-Mor месяц-полтора, точно уже не скажу

Comment: Просто, чисто моё мнение (не утверждаю, что оно правильное) такое: лучше сначала изучить язык как следует, а уже потом реализовать на нём нечто рабочее. Тогда Вы сами сможете разобраться в проблемах и найти необходимые Вам методы улучшения. Все советы, которые Вам дадут здесь, будут мало чем полезны без понимания того, что происходит.

Comment: @V-Mor знаю что сначала нужно розобраться, но просто если сказать честно, и за большого количества библиотек для python, не всегда можно понять что лучше использовать. Но  основы python, я понял сразу(кроме роботы с dict и list) так как до этого писал на C++ и начинал с Pascal, так что синтаксиси практически что похожы

Comment: В Python и без сторонних библиотек есть с чем поразбираться, об этом целые книги пишут.

Comment: @V-Mor Можете подсказать ответ на второй вопрос(WIndows)

Answer (score 0):

**Как лучше сделать, чтобы он работал:**

Использовать `webhook`, который очень просто реализовать на бесплатном хостинге [www.pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com):

1) Зарегистрироваться
2) web - >create new -> Flask -> python 3.7
3) в сгенерированном на п.2 файле ввести такой код:

```
import telebot # pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
from config import TOKEN, SECRET, URL 
#URL = "https://nameofmysite.pythonanywhere.com/" 
#- этот адрес виден назакладке web после создания приложения, 
# SECRET = "anylettersanddigits" - любой набор цифр и букв

from flask import Flask, request, abort

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN, threaded=False)
bot.remove_webhook()
url = URL + SECRET
bot.set_webhook(url = url)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/{}'.format(SECRET), methods=["POST"])
def telegram_webhook():
    if request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        # json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        json_string = request.stream.read().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return 'ok', 200
    else:
        abort(403)

# 
# код программы
#

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello!'
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Переписать на aiogram, чтобы уменьшить количество обращений и сохранять состояния.

3 Сервера телеги разрывают соединения на которых ничего не происходит продолжительное время.